# Resource not found when accessed through POST method, but the resource gets downloaded when opened from the browser's address bar

Tags: php, jquery, post, contact-form

I am using a template to create my portfolio website. At the bottom of this template website, there is a contact me section.

When I try to send my details across through the contact form, it shows a 404 error.
`jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:3000/assets/mail/contact_me.php 404 (Not Found)`

But when I paste this link in the address bar (`http://localhost:3000/assets/mail/contact_me.php`), it downloads the contact_me.php file.

Any idea why the POST method returns a 404 error?

Below is the code of the contact from (it's in pug format):

```
form#contactForm(name='sentMessage', novalidate='novalidate')
  .control-group
    .form-group.floating-label-form-group.controls.mb-0.pb-2
      label Name
      input#name.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Name', required='required', data-validation-required-message='Please enter your name.')
      p.help-block.text-danger
  .control-group
    .form-group.floating-label-form-group.controls.mb-0.pb-2
      label Email Address
      input#email.form-control(type='email', placeholder='Email Address', required='required', data-validation-required-message='Please enter your email address.')
      p.help-block.text-danger
  .control-group
    .form-group.floating-label-form-group.controls.mb-0.pb-2
      label Phone Number
      input#phone.form-control(type='tel', placeholder='Phone Number', required='required', data-validation-required-message='Please enter your phone number.')
      p.help-block.text-danger
  .control-group
    .form-group.floating-label-form-group.controls.mb-0.pb-2
      label Message
      textarea#message.form-control(rows='5', placeholder='Message', required='required', data-validation-required-message='Please enter a message.')
      p.help-block.text-danger
  br
  #success
    .form-group
      button#sendMessageButton.btn.btn-primary.btn-xl(type='submit') Send
```

Mail should be posted after the input from jQuery. Code of *contact_me.js* is below:

```
$(function () {
    $(
        "#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea,#contactForm button"
    ).jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function ($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function ($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(" ") >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ");
            }
            $this = $("#sendMessageButton");
            $this.prop("disabled", true); // Disable submit button until AJAX call is complete to prevent duplicate messages
            $.ajax({
                url: "/assets/mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message,
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function () {
                    // Success message
                    $("#success").html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $("#success > .alert-success")
                        .html(
                            "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;"
                        )
                        .append("</button>");
                    $("#success > .alert-success").append(
                        "<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>"
                    );
                    $("#success > .alert-success").append("</div>");
                    //clear all fields
                    $("#contactForm").trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function () {
                    // Fail message
                    $("#success").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $("#success > .alert-danger")
                        .html(
                            "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;"
                        )
                        .append("</button>");
                    $("#success > .alert-danger").append(
                        $("<strong>").text(
                            "Sorry " +
                                firstName +
                                ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!"
                        )
                    );
                    $("#success > .alert-danger").append("</div>");
                    //clear all fields
                    $("#contactForm").trigger("reset");
                },
                complete: function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $this.prop("disabled", false); // Re-enable submit button when AJAX call is complete
                    }, 1000);
                },
            });
        },
        filter: function () {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});

/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$("#name").focus(function () {
    $("#success").html("");
});
```

Below is the code of *contact_me.php*

```php
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['phone']) || empty($_POST['message']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  http_response_code(500);
  exit();
}

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = "hp.onenonly@gmail.com"; // Add your email address in between the "" replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$header = "From: noreply@harish-prabhu.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$header .= "Reply-To: $email";

if(!mail($to, $subject, $body, $header))
  http_response_code(500);
?>
```

Comment: Where and how is this being used in jQuery?

Comment: please post the actual code of the form